# How can I get a deleted answer undeleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, undelete-request

I answered this question with a link to the vendor documentation that I believed addressed the issue.

[Adding description to a web intelligence document in BOBJ 42sp6 using restapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032658/adding-description-to-a-web-intelligence-document-in-bobj-42sp6-using-restapi)

My answer was deleted because...

> Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

That make sense to me. So I edited my answer to replicate the pertinent information from link I provide while still referencing the link.

How do I get my answer undeleted? I voted to undelete it, but I get a message that says "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted".

I understand wanting to not allow answers that could become stale (dead links). Should I post a new answer with the information from the link?

Thanks

Comment: You can find your answer in the FAQ on deletion: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: @isaac you copied content directly from the linked page. Do you have permission to do that? It would be a shame if your new answer had to be deleted because it's now plagiarised rather than link-only.

Comment: @RobertLongson you're joking, right? Yes, I copied it because the moderator said I couldn't just have a link and I also referenced the link. The documentation is the documentation. I don't believe I should change it.

Comment: If your answer is nothing but a copy paste, are you sure you've properly answered the question?  It adds nothing to address the specific case, as documentation is meant to address general use, not specific scenarios.  Answers of that type are usually very low quality.  Put in some effort!  Point at the docs, and show how to use them to solve the specific problem!

Comment: The question was general, "How do I do X?". My answer was a link to the product documentation on "How to do X." If my answer gets undeleted we can let the OP determine if it answered the question. If not, we can go from there. No one else has come along with another answer.

Comment: As answers go...that's really poor.  If I see it, I would downvote it in a heartbeat.  A copy paste is little better than a link by itself.  We except posters to invest at least a little bit of effort into their post.  Considering the comment you left, it'd be better to wait for someone familiar with the problem space to answer.

Comment: So it would be better to leave it unanswered?

Comment: I am not looking for a fight here. I just want to know what the proper thing to do is. In the view of the community it seems like it would have been better for me to leave this question answered. Would a link to the documentation been better as comment? I well versed with the product referenced in the question, but not the particular feature on which the question was asked. I thought I could help the OP by pointing them in the right direction. That's it.

Comment: A comment would be fine.  An answer would be borderline, at best, as there is no familiarity with the issue, and all you're doing is pasting documentation.  We want high quality answers from experts, that directly solve the problem.  Just pointing users in the right direction means well, but doesn't do much to actually solve it.

Comment: "should I post a new answer with the information from the link?" - Your new answer will likely be flagged as a duplicate of the deleted answer.  DO NOT do this. Flag your existing question for a moderator attention

Comment: So while I am learning the rules here my question keeps getting voted down. That doesn't really encourage discussion and engagement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your post was deleted by a moderator, then only a moderator can undelete it.  You can flag your deleted post to point out the edit and request undeletion.  If that doesn't work, you'll need to raise the issue for discussion on your site's meta.

Comment: I didn't realize that was the purpose of a flag. I just assumed a "flag" was to complain about something and I wasn't looking to complain. I just wanted the moderator to review my edited answer. So this is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Isaac *a* purpose, anyway.  Use custom flags for stuff that you/the community can't handle yourselves.  Actions that only mods can take qualify.